# Agrupar produtos por categorias vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Tenho um componente que exibo produtos e tenho um h2 onde exibo o nome da categoria. O problema é que aparecem os nomes das categorias repetidas, já que dois produtos pertencem a mesma categoria. Gostaria de exibir o título "Categoria 1" e após isso os produtos, sem repetir o "Categoria 1" novamente para o produto 2.

Array Categories:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: Categoria 1,
}
```

Array Products:

```
  {
     id: 10
     name: Produto 1,
     category_id: 1
  },
  {
     id: 11,
     name: Produto 2,
     category_id: 1
  }
```

Componente:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
        <h2 class="text-danger font-weight-bold mt-3" v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id" :value="category.id" v-if="category.id === product.category_id">{{ category.name }}</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-modal">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h3 class="text-danger font-weight-bold">{{ product.name }}</h3>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "CategoryProduct",
    data() {
        return {
            categories: [],
            products: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getCategories() {
            axios
                .get('/api/categories')
                .then(response => {
                    this.categories = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        },
        getProducts() {
            axios
                .get('/api/products')
                .then(response => {
                    this.products = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getCategories();
        this.getProducts();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Dê um exemplo de como são os objetos dentro de `categories`, você quer agrupá-los pelo `category.name`? - É preferível criar um exemplo somente com o código necessário para reproduzir o problema, tua pergunta tem código em excesso. - [ask]

Comment: Reduzi o código e coloquei o exmplo. Quero agrupar pelo nome da categoria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As categorias estão se repetindo, pois você está utilizando o primeiro `v-for` com os produtos, em vez de utilizar a variável de produtos.

O que você precisa fazer é percorrer as categorias conforme isso, você vai filtrando os produtos através dos campos `product.categoryId` e `category.id`. No meu exemplo, fiz uma função `filterProducts` para fazer a tarefa supramencionada.

Desta forma, em vez de utilizar `products in products`, utilizaremos `products in filterProducts(category.id)`.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      categories: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Categoria #1'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Categoria #2'
      }],
      products: [{
        id: 10,
        name: 'Produto 1',
        categoryId: 1
      }, {
        id: 20,
        name: 'Produto 2',
        categoryId: 1
      }, {
        id: 30,
        name: 'Produto 3',
        categoryId: 2
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * Filtra os produtos conforme o ID da categoria
     * @params {Number}
     * @returns {Array}
     */
    filterProducts(categoryId) {
      return this.products.filter(p => p.categoryId === categoryId)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="category in categories">
      {{ category.name }}
      <ul>
        <li v-for="product in filterProducts(category.id)">
          {{ product.name }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Há também outra forma de fazer isso, basta usar o `v-if` para "filtrar" os produtos. Segue exemplo abaixo.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      categories: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Categoria #1'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Categoria #2'
      }],
      products: [{
        id: 10,
        name: 'Produto 1',
        categoryId: 1
      }, {
        id: 20,
        name: 'Produto 2',
        categoryId: 1
      }, {
        id: 30,
        name: 'Produto 3',
        categoryId: 2
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="category in categories">
      {{ category.name }}
      <ul>
        <li
          v-for="product in products"
          v-if="product.categoryId == category.id"
        >
          {{ product.name }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```